# Values only readable inside API call

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I am trying to append my object with data which is coming from API call. My for loop is appending it but I can read it only inside the API call. Why? I can't understand it.

I have custom array object:

```
var locations: [Locations] = []
```

This is my API call:

```
    Configuration().API_URL.get("test") { (error, data: [Response]?) in
                for response in data!{
                    self.locations.append(Locations(latitude: response.latitude))
                }
                //If I print the print(locations) here, it prints
        }
//If I do the print(locations) here(outside of API call), it does print empty object
```

Why I can't get output from the locations outside of the API call if I did append it and the values does exist? I am sure it is some stupid question but my mind is blown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a closure that is called asynchronously.

It's a bit of a broad topic, but essentially everything in the curly braces after the call to `get`, i.e. this stuff:

```
{ (error, data: [Response]?) in
    for response in data! {
        self.locations.append(Locations(latitude: response.latitude))
    }
    //If I print the print(locations) here, it prints
}
```

Is code that gets executed *after* the network call finishes.  You're passing a "closure", or a block of code to be executed later, to the `get()` method.

Since it isn't called immediately, after calling `get()` your code continues to the next line where, as you've noted, `locations` is empty.

Only later, when the `get()` function finishes, does it call the code in the closure and that's when you can append to `locations`.

I suggest you read up on closures and asynchronous calls in Swift for more information.

Comment: Ohh.. I totally understand it now. Thank you for clearing it up :) It is actually pretty obvious :D